# chances of getting a target number or above by rolling multiple dice

Tags: statistics

I had this idea to expand upon the advantage system used by D&D 5e and Pathfinder as a core mechanic for another system.  I need to know what the progression is like for adding another die to the roll.

Edit: to clarify, adding a die means having another chance for any 1 of the dice to possibly hit or exceed the target number, not adding the numbers of the dice together.

So for a d20 with target number 20, i would think adding another d20 would bring the chance to 10% instead of 5%.  And then adding a third would be 15%.

I'm no good with statistics however, so i have no idea whether the progession is actually linear or not.  Any help would be appreciated.

Also, i'm using target number 20 for simplicity's sake, but once i know the progression, i can figure the rest out myself.

Comment: This is an interesting question, however it's probably better suited to stats.stackexchange.com. By the way, you should probably clarify in what way the dice are combined -- do you mean to actually add the numbers? Or just that if you get the target number on any one of n dice, you win? It's not clear what you mean by "add".

Comment: @RobertDodier edited for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the clarification. The probability of rolling 20 (or any other specific number) increases a little more slowly than linearly, since some of the 20's are "wasted" when two or more dice result in 20.

The question is, what is P(d1 = 20 or d2 = 20 or d3 = 20 or ...). It turns out that computing probability of "or" is more complicated, but the probability of "and" is simpler. So let's restate the question equivalently using "and": d1 = 20 or d2 = 20 or d3 = 20 or ... is the same as not(d1 not= 20 and d2 not= 20 and d3 not= 20 and ...). Assuming that rolling each die is independent of the others (this is an important, substantial assumption which should always be considered carefully), then P(d1 not= 20 and d2 not= 20 and ...) is the same as P(d1 not= 20) times P(d2 not= 20) times ....

Now P(not something) = 1 - P(something), so P(d not= 20) = 1 - P(d = 20), where d is any one of the dice, and P(not(d1 not= 20 and d2 not= 20 and ...)) = 1 - ((1 - P(d1 = 20)) times (1 - P(d2 = 20)) times ...).

We're almost there. Assuming (again this should be considered carefully) that all the dice are the same, P(dj = 20) = P(dk = 20) for all j and k. So (1 - P(d1 = 20)) times (1 - P(d2 = 20) times ... = (1 - P(d = 20))^n where n is the number of dice.

P(d = i) = 1/m where m is the number of faces (20 in this example) and i is any one of the faces, i = 1, 2, 3, ..., m. In particular, P(d = 20) = 1/20 in this example.

Putting it all together, P(any one die = 20) = 1 - (1 - 1/20)^n where n is the number of dice.

For n = 1, 2, 3, ..., we have 1/20, 39/400, 1141/8000, .... i.e., 0.05, 0.0975, 0.142625, .... As you can see, P(any one die = 20) grows a little more slowly than linearly with the number of dice.

To get more practice with problems of this kind, you can look up "laws of probability" or "rules of probability". A web search should turn up a lot of examples.